# Prove $\sup_{B_{1/2}(0)} |D^k u| \leq C \| u \|_{L^2(B_1(0))}$, and why do we have $L^2$ norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, harmonic-functions

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be harmonic on $B_1(0)$, the ball of radius one centered at $0$. I saw this result that

$$ \sup_{B_{1/2}(0)} |D^k u| \leq C \| u \|_{L^2(B_1(0))}$$

where $k \geq 0$ is an integer, and $C = C(n,k)$.

I think induction works.

Attempt for $k=1$: Let $x_0 \in B_{1/2}(0)$. Then we have for $r=1/8$

$$ |u_{x_i}(x_0)| = \Big| C \int_{B_r(x_0)} u_{x_i} dx \Big| = \Big| \frac{C}{r^n} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0)} u \nu_i ds \Big| \leq C \|u\|_{L^\infty(\partial B_r(x_0))} $$

where we have used the Mean Value Property, and divergence theorem, and $C= C(n)$.

For $x \in \partial B_r(x_0)$ we have by MVP,

$$ u(x) = \frac{C}{r^n} \int_{B_r(x)} u(x) dx \leq \frac{C}{r^n} \int_{B_1(x)} u(x) dx =  C \| u \|_{L^1(B_1(0))}$$

So
$$  |u_{x_i}(x_0)| \leq C \| u \|_{L^1(B_1(0))} \leq C \| u \|_{L^2(B_2(0))} $$

Is this method correct?

**Question:** I understand we can bound the $L^1$ norm in terms of the $L^2$ norm, but why not leave the result in terms of $L^1$? And why stop at $L^2$ why not go higher?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing the context that you saw the result. But: $L^2$ is special, as it is closely related to the energy structure (Dirichlet's principle) for the equation. If you try proving such estimates for more complicated equations (even $\Delta u = f$, say), often an estimate by $L^2$ can be obtained by energy arguments (multiply PDE by $u$ times a cutoff, integrate by parts), but to go below $L^2$ really requires something potential-theoretic in nature (i.e. using the fundamental solution). MVP is a very strong potential-theoretic argument that doesn't usually generalize.

Comment: @user378654 Ah I see thanks. The context is harmonic approximation